# Extending razor view engine for post processing of html

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I would like to perform some post processing on the html that the view engine renders in response to an action request.

Scenario: request for /foo/12 comes in and the FooController returns a view generated from {Action}.cshtml. I would like to get this Html and munge it in some way (not important).

Is this possible? Do I need to write my own view engine for this? Can I extend the razor view engine to make my dream possible?

Regards,

J

Comment: why do you wan to "munge" the html? If it is a template that you want to write then you could make the html conform to that so you dont have to go to the hassle of writing your own view engine implementation

Comment: I've got a bunch of view templates that specify the html I want rendered for each view. However, in certain circumstances I want add some html attributes to the markup for each view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do this by using a [Response Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.filter.aspx) and an ActionFilter. See http://www.tombatron.com/Articles/Custom-Response-Filters-for-ASPNET-MVC

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing that I know of that will allow you to inspect, and further modify the HTML that is returned from a view. Perhaps your best solution is to figure out what it is that changes in your views and handle them in the view itself.