# Filtering the output of my ASP.NET MVC views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to do some additional processing of the output of all my views before they get sent to the client.

I tried setting the view base class to a custom class where I override `Execute`, but that doesn't work because Razor will generate its own `Execute` in the derived class that doesn't call mine.

Is there another MVC-specific way to do it, or my only hope is to resort to the "classic" way of doing it, by setting `Response.Filter` in `Application_BeginRequest` in Global.asax?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extending razor view engine for post processing of html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041481/extending-razor-view-engine-for-post-processing-of-html)

Comment: What kind of additional processing?

Comment: Replacing some strings with other strings in the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement [IResultFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iresultfilter.aspx). Common way to do it is by deriving from [ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.aspx)

```
void OnResultExecuted(
    ResultExecutedContext filterContext
)
```

Comment: So I would have to add that attribute to all my actions in all my controllers?

Comment: You can create a global action filter so you don't have to add it to each. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvcglobalanddynamicactionfilters_topic2.aspx

Comment: You could add that to controller to apply to all actions of that controller, and even in Global.asax as Global filter to apply to all actions